# Change an amount of values in column to np.nan based on value in other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Like the title states I want to change values in 'Vorgabe' and 'Temp' to nan, based on the value in 'Cut'.

This is an example with the desired outcome. I think that is the best way to understand my problem.

```
     OptOpTemp  OpTemp  Grad  Vorgabe  Temp  Cut
0        22.5      24   0.0     22.5    24   0.0
1        22.5      24   0.0     22.5    24   0.0
2        23.5      24   1.0     23.5    24   1.0
3        23.5      24   0.0     23.5    24   0.0
4        23.5      24   0.0     23.5    24   0.0
5        23.5      24   0.0     23.5    24   0.0
6        23.5      24   0.0     23.5    24   0.0
7        23.5      24   0.0     23.5    24   0.0
8        23.5      24   0.0     23.5    24   0.0
9        26.0      24   2.5     26.0    24   3.0
10       26.0      24   0.0     26.0    24   0.0
11       26.0      24   0.0     26.0    24   0.0
12       26.0      24   0.0     26.0    24   0.0
13       26.0      24   0.0     26.0    24   0.0
```

I want to change this to this:

```
     OptOpTemp  OpTemp  Grad  Vorgabe  Temp  Cut
0        22.5      24   0.0     22.5    24   0.0
1        22.5      24   0.0     nan    nan   0.0 <- one row above
2        23.5      24   1.0     nan    nan   1.0
3        23.5      24   0.0     nan    nan   0.0 <- one row among
4        23.5      24   0.0     23.5    24   0.0
5        23.5      24   0.0     23.5    24   0.0
6        23.5      24   0.0     nan    nan   0.0 <- three rows above
7        23.5      24   0.0     nan    nan   0.0
8        23.5      24   0.0     nan    nan   0.0
9        26.0      24   2.5     nan    nan   3.0
10       26.0      24   0.0     nan    nan   0.0
11       26.0      24   0.0     nan    nan   0.0
12       26.0      24   0.0     nan    nan   0.0 <- three rows among
13       26.0      24   0.0     26.0    24   0.0
```

The amount of rows above and among is based on the value in 'Cut'.

I want to create this for every integer value in 'Cut'. So if there occurs a 2 it should cut two rows above and two among. Therefore I think a loop would be needed, but I don't know how to achieve the right outcome...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to create an array of indices and mask by them:

```
# define in-scope cuts
cuts = df.loc[df['Cut'] != 0, 'Cut'].astype(int)

# calculate array of indices
idx = np.hstack([np.arange(i - val, i + val + 1) for i, val in cuts.items()])

# mask series according to indices
df.loc[idx, ['Vorgabe', 'Temp']] = np.nan

# alternative: use if index ranges may fall out of dataframe index
# df.loc[df.index.isin(idx), ['Vorgabe', 'Temp']] = np.nan

print(df)

#     OptOpTemp  OpTemp  Grad  Vorgabe  Temp  Cut
# 0        22.5      24   0.0     22.5  24.0  0.0
# 1        22.5      24   0.0      NaN   NaN  0.0
# 2        23.5      24   1.0      NaN   NaN  1.0
# 3        23.5      24   0.0      NaN   NaN  0.0
# 4        23.5      24   0.0     23.5  24.0  0.0
# 5        23.5      24   0.0     23.5  24.0  0.0
# 6        23.5      24   0.0      NaN   NaN  0.0
# 7        23.5      24   0.0      NaN   NaN  0.0
# 8        23.5      24   0.0      NaN   NaN  0.0
# 9        26.0      24   2.5      NaN   NaN  3.0
# 10       26.0      24   0.0      NaN   NaN  0.0
# 11       26.0      24   0.0      NaN   NaN  0.0
# 12       26.0      24   0.0      NaN   NaN  0.0
# 13       26.0      24   0.0     26.0  24.0  0.0
```